# On the origin of "blizzard"

Tags: etymology

*Blizzard* is probably the most used word to indicate a violent snowstorm. Despite its popularity the etymology of the term is quite unclear. Some well-known  sources hint  at its onomatopoeic sound as its possible origin.  Can anyone offer a reliable story behind this term or just confirm its 'obscure' origin?

[Blizzard](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Blizzard&searchmode=none): (etymonline)

> - strong, sustained snowstorm," 1859, origin obscure (perhaps somehow connected with blaze (n.1)); it came into general use in the U.S. in this sense the hard winter 1880-81. OED says it probably is "more or less onomatopœic," and adds "there is nothing to indicate a French origin."

[Blizzard](http://blog.oup.com/2008/01/blizzard/): (Oxford University Press):

> - In British rural speech, there existed a sound imitative complex blizz expressing the idea of great quickness. When the suffix -ard was added to it, the new word began to denote all kinds of things having an immediate effect on its victim, from “a gunshot” to “an intoxicating drink.”
>
>   Most records are from American English. In 1870, in Iowa, a violent snowstorm was called a blizzard. Storms and hurricanes travel fast. Today blizzard is an established part of the vocabulary of English. What else do we not know about its history? -

Comment: Having lived in the US Midwest for 40 years I've lived through a number of blizzards (though fewer and fewer recently).  The origin of the word is occasionally discussed in newspaper weather columns, and it's always come back to mid-1800s Iowa, from whose forehead it seems to have magically sprung.

Comment: Though _blizzard_ doesn't appear in this [list of simplex words with the `BL-` assonance](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/bl.pdf) (since _blizzard_ isn't a simplex word), note that the meaning of _blizzard_ is coherent with all three senses of the `BL-` assonance class: `Excess/Too Much` (obviously), `Color/Eye` (think _white-out_), and `Contained Fluid` (again obviously, though not until it starts to melt).

Comment: @JohnLawler - so, you are  giving credit to  the 'onomatopoeic' assumption!

Comment: It's not onomatopoeia. Onomatopoeia is words that resemble the sound they refer too, like "swish" or "boom". It's a very small and unimportant phenomenon, since how often do we discuss sounds? There **is**  an aural component to blizzards -- the wind makes a noise -- but it's the visual, tactile, white, wet, blinding, blinking excess that this refers to. It's phonosemantic, not onomatopoeic. See [the paper this chart came from](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/WomenMen&BristlyThings.pdf), or explain [the `KL-` chart](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/kl-chart.pdf) as a coincidence.

Comment: Really astonishing that the origin of a word that isn't older than about 150 years is obscure. By the way, I can't see or hear any sound imitation in the word blizzard. Perhaps it was shortened from a paraphrase, something like "a snow storm that blasts hard and long".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My original response to this question is so long that I was asked to convert it into a [blog post](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2015/02/where-did-blizzard-come-from-the-too-long-did-not-read-version/?cb=1).  That answer has four main sections.

The first section looks at nineteenth-century American discussions of the various slang meanings of *blizzard*—which include “a stunning blow,” “an unanswerable question or argument,” and “a violent and destructive snow-storm”—and their possible origin. The second section reviews analyses of *blizzard* by British writers between 1888 and 1921, with a particular focus on its arguable connection to Midlands dialect words such as *blizzer*, *blizzom*, and *blizzy*. The third section notes attempts by more-recent etymologists to identify the roots of the word (in French, German, Anglo-Saxon, or elsewhere) and to pinpoint where the snowstorm meaning of blizzard originated. On all of these points, no clear scholarly consensus emerges.

Finally, in the fourth section of my answer/blog post, I look at occurrences of *blizzard* in publications dated between 1834 and 1870 (the date of the first authenticated newspaper use of the word to refer to a snowstorm). Of the 34 unique instances of *blizzard* that I cite in that section, 12 refer to a blast or volley from one or more firearms or cannons, 8 refer to verbal blasts, 7 to a heavy or painful physical blow not involving a firearm, 3 to a literal or figurative attack that is not otherwise identified, 2 to a mild oath, 1 to a blazing fire, and 1 to a shot of liquor. Especially interesting is the emergence during the U.S. Civil War period of *blizzard* in the sense of a volley or fusillade of bullets, which provides a more satisfying immediate source meaning of the word lading up to the fierce snowstorm meaning than do the earlier blazing fire and stunning blow meanings.

The origin of *blizzard* in the sense of snowstorm remains somewhat mysterious, but the evidence of U.S. usage prior to 1870 suggests that the word had appeared in newspapers across the nation and that it had multiple active meanings as a slang term in 1870. Under the circumstances, the notion that *blizzard* in the sense of snowstorm may simply have been some sort of onomatopoeic invention of an Iowa newspaperman—and only coincidentally identical to the slang word *blizzard* as used in other contemporaneous senses—seems quite far-fetched.

Comment: The original certainly was "quite long". It was an "active" post when I started reading it - but before I finished, the screen auto-updated itself and I found I was reading a deleted post! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Yes, it's been a learning experience for me to see the effects of my inclination toward completeness. Like perfectionism, that inclination can be seriously counterproductive (to put it mildly). In future, I'll try to do a better job of reining in my tendencies in that direction.

Comment: Serendipity, or secret connection?: http://www.merriam-webster.com/blog/one-more-problem-with-blizzards.htm

Comment: @Hellion: Thanks for the link. That blog post is actually a light rewrite of the entry for _blizzard_ in _Webster's Word Histories_ (1989). In fact, part of what inspired me to detail as many relevant instances of the use of _blizzard_ in the period between 1835 and 1870 was my disagreement with the tendency of the assertion (using the _Webster's Word Histories_ wording here) that "The earlier uses appear to have been short-lived or local; the gun blast sense overlaps the snowstorm sense in time, but is attested only from other parts of the country.” ...

Comment: ...As I pointed out, the firearm/cannon blast/fusillade meaning occurs in newspaper stories published between 1835 and 1863 in Louisiana, Maryland, Michigan, Ohio, Pennsylvania, Tennessee, and Vermont, as well as in three books. Blizzard was also used in other senses in newspaper articles published in California, Georgia, Indiana, Kansas, Louisiana, Missouri, Nebraska, New York, Virginia, West Virginia, and elsewhere. Given the great commingling of people from older settled states westward after the Civil War, I think that Webster’s “short-lived or local” characterization is inaccurate. ...

Comment: ...(Newspapers in a number of other states and published their own versions of some of the articles I cited; I reported only the earliest occurrence of each story in the Library of Congress database.) I can’t blame Merriam-Webster for conclusions it reached on the basis of (relatively) spotty source data back in 1989; but I hope that in future it will take advantage of available online databases to do a serious followup investigation of a word's history—and will update its earlier conclusions accordingly—instead of publishing what is essentially a cosmetically altered 26-year-old article.

Answer (score 2):

More background on the possible German origins:

Lyon County News, 2 March 1883:

"The word blizzard was first used in Marshall, Minnesota, by an American settler, now residing in Iowa. It was in the storm of 1873, at Charles H. Whitney's Hotel, and the man was Deacon Seth Knowles, who was a settler of Lyon county near this village. The Deacon was a fine German scholar, and while discussing the terrible storm raging without, one speaker said no word could express its severity, whereupon the deacon said: "It's a Blizzard."

"So the great storm of 1873 was locally known, and with recurring storms the term spread through the state. During late years it has been generally adopted for squalls in the eastern states, which as compared with a genuine blizzard are no more than zephyrs. The deacon knew what he was talking about and adapted the term to the terrors of the storm. A German witnessing one of these overpowering storms would say: "Der Sturm commit blitzartig,' which, translated into English, would be: 'The storm comes lightning-like.'

The translation from blitzartig to blizzard is natural and easy, while no word could better describe the oncoming snow and wind storm, and certainly there is no English word to fill the bill. The newness if the term and its pronunciation led the deacon to step to the counter of the hotel and write the word for the benefit of his friends."

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere along the line I read that "blizzard" was derived from the German "blitz," which is a sudden and drastic onslaught of something. That pretty well describes what a blizzard is.